# Why an old Nodejs version is installed on my Ubuntu machine

Tags: 16.04, apt, nodejs

I installed Nodejs on my Ubuntu:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
```

with the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
sudo apt-get install npm
```

The result is:

```
$ nodejs -v
v4.2.6
```

In the internet I see there much newer versions https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/ .
So,

1. Why such old version is installed by default
2. How to install newer one?

Thank you!

Comment: Because you use a 5 year old version of Ubuntu ... update to a newer ubuntu version to get newer software. Update path is 16.04 >> 18.04 >> 20.04, or make a new install 0f 20.04 directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`4.2.6` is indeed the version of Node that is in the Xenial repos. Ubuntu does not do major version updates of packages within the same distribution, so if Node 4 was what was around when Xenial came out (which is to say, April of 2016, which sounds about right -- it would have been the then-current LTS release), then you're stuck with version 4 all the way through Xenial's lifetime until you upgrade the distro.

At least, that's the case when using the official repositories. Fortunately, a more up-to-date repository for Node does exist and is recommended on Node's official site. You can find detailed instructions [here](https://github.com/nodesource/distributions/blob/master/README.md), but the tl;dr is:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has this version of nodejs because it was one of the LTS versions (long term support) and is very stable.

There are a few different ways to install newer versions. I would recommend installing it through nvm so you get access to the latest versions. Plus it helps to do it this way if you will be developing on multiple systems rather than leaving it up to the systems package manager. To do this first remove the current version

`sudo apt-get remove nodejs`

To ensure it's completely removed you can do `sudo apt-get purge nodejs` and `sudo apt-get autoremove`

Now we can prepare to use npm by installing `build-essential` and `libssl-dev`

`sudo apt-get install build-essential libssl-dev`

Now we can download the nvm installation script from the projects Github page

`curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.8/install.sh -o install_nvm.sh`

Run the install script with

`bash install_nvm.sh`

At this point it is easiest to logout, and then log back in to complete the setup of npm.

Now we can use the following commands to install the target nodejs version

`npm ls-remote` shows you the available versions

`npm install (versionNumber)`

`npm use (versionNumber)` You can have multiple versions installed so you can choose which one to use

then verify the version you have chosen to use with

`node -v` <- Please note that with npm the command is node and NOT nodejs

There is a great write up about all of this on Digital Ocean. For more information visit the link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Great instructions, but I believe you've got three typos towards the end. It should be `nvm ls-remote`, `nvm install (versionNumber)` and `nvm use (versionNumber)`.